# Homotopic paths and Deformation Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, homotopy-theory

This is a general question about homotopic paths. Is it always true that if you have a simple, closed, positively-oriented curve $\gamma$, a point $a$ inside it anda function $f(z)$ which is holomorphic on and inside $\gamma$ then $\int_\gamma f(z)dz = \int_{\gamma_{(a,r)}}f(z)dz$, where $\gamma_{(a,r)}$ is a positively oriented circle centred at $\gamma$ with radius $r$ such that it is entirely in $\gamma$? I feel like this follows from the fact that a simple, closed curve divides the complex plane in $2$ sets by the Jordan's Curve Theorem and every $\gamma_{(a_1,r_1)}$, $\gamma_{(a_2,r_2)}$ are homotopic in the complex plane and hence in the interior. I can't seem to formulate it rigorously enough, I think in order to apply the Deformation Theorem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If $f$ is not holomorphic on any points in the annulus given by $\gamma$ and $\gamma_{(a,r)}$, then this is not true. Deformation of paths is valid when you can "move through" holomorphic points.

Comment: I am assuming that $f$ is holomorphic on all of the interior of $\gamma$. Then it is supposed to hold since we can treat the interior as a subset of the complex plane?

Comment: If $f$ is holomorphic on and interior to $\gamma$, then the integral is zero, by Cauchy-Goursat, as is the integral about any positive simple closed curve interior to $\gamma$. So yes, you are correct!

Comment: Ah, I see, so as long as we guarantee that Cauchy's theorem holds, we can continuously deformate the paths so that we still get integrals equal to 0. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ok, it seems that it wasn't clear enough :). What happens if we have a singularity? So basically, my textbook says that $\int_{\gamma}\frac{f(w)}{w-a}dw = \int_{\gamma_{(a,r)}}\frac{f(w)}{w-a}dw$ for any circle $\gamma_{((a,r)} $ contained in $\gamma$ under the usual conditions for $\gamma$ and $f(z)$. Why does this still hold? If possible, can you not use the residue theorem, since this proof is sort of a prerequisite(it's in the proof of the Cauchy's Integral Formula)