# A Homotopy-Based Proof of the Cauchy's Integral Formula?

Tags: complex-analysis, homotopy-theory, cauchy-integral-formula

Suppose that we have proved the Cauchy's Integral Formula for positively oriented circles, and that now we want to prove a more general version for piecewise smooth Jordan curves. This can be done by proving a statement similar to the following one:

> Let $\gamma$ be a positively oriented piecewise smooth Jordan curve and $C$  a positively oriented circle in its interior cenetered at $a$. Let $f$ be holomorphic inside and on $\gamma$, possibly with a single exception at $z = a$. Then $$\int_{\gamma}f(z)\,\mathrm{d}z = \int_C f(z)\,\mathrm{d}z.$$

Now, this is usually proved by "joining" $\gamma$ and $C$ by some path(s), so that one is finally able to apply Cauchy's integral theorem (technical details seem to be unimportant here).

However, one point keeps me bothering here: I cannot prove or disprove the following conjecture:

> Let $\gamma$ and $C$ be as above. Then $\gamma$ is $(G \setminus \{a\})$-homotopic to $C$, where $G$ is the union of (the image of) $\gamma$ with its interior.

Is this true? If so, then the former statement could be proved by simply applying the "Deformation theorem" asserting equality of integrals along homotopic curves.

(Seems to be related to the last comment under [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2300124/homotopic-paths-and-deformation-theorem).)

*One more point*: I am mostly interested in an "elementary" resolution of the above question. In particular, I would prefer to avoid concepts like index or the most general form of Cauchy's theorem, which do not seem to be needed (in fact, this implies that a "better" formulation of the above statements would disregard orientation and simply assert that they are true for $\gamma$ or for $-\gamma$).

Comment: By the Jordan curve theorem, the statement you want is equivalent to the fact that the fundamental group of the punctured disc (in the plane) is $\mathbb{Z}$, so it really depends on what you consider "elementary" - I would suggest consulting a text of algebraic topology for that

Comment: I doubt that there's a _really_ elementary proof. Since one of the hypotheses is that $C$ lies in the interior of $\gamma$,  and it takes something that seems not so elementary to me to _define_ "the interior of $\gamma$"

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Well, yes, the Jordan curve theorem is obviously needed already to give a precise formulation of the result. However, I think that it is also assumed by many elementary texts approaching the Cauchy theory, so I am of course willing to assume it as well.

Comment: @Conrad It indeed seems that I might have a trouble to define exactly what I mean by "elementary". Thanks for a pointer anyway.

Comment: @Conrad However, I am not sure whether the statement is exactly the same as yours. Isn't there a problem with a possibility of non-holomorphy outside $\gamma$? If $f$ was holomorphic on $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{a\}$, then I would have some ideas how to approach the proof in an "elementary" way...

Comment: I was talking about the homotopy statement above (which has nothing to do with holomorphy per se) if you use just JCT as it seemed to me that was the main question; obviously if you want to use Riemann mapping theorem, that's different, but not really needed here

Comment: It  strikes me as curious that you say you want to avoid the concept of "index" because it's not elementary enough, but you have no problem assuming JCT. Whatever. Yes, a lot of elementary texts do assume JCT without proof, often without even saying they're assuming it. But it's not hard to do more or less all the complex  analysis you need without ever mentioning anything JCT-ish. (_Real and Cmplex Analysis_, _Comple Made Simple_...)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I agree, absolutely. I am just curious if this particular proof of the Cauchy's formula can be simplified or not...